# Cryptomatte outputs one or two colors only

Tags: cryptomatte

This may be me just being a Blender noobie, but when I try to render a Cryptomatte pass I only get one or two colors, usually green or white, with full alpha transparency for some reason (I had to check in the Image Editor to show RGB only so I could at least see what the pass rendered). The other passes seem to render OK, though.

Is there a setting I need to check or is it a bug? I'm using Blender 2.81a. Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Possibly related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/143706/cryptomatte-doesnt-output-nice-clean-edges/144220?r=SearchResults#144220

Comment: How are you viewing the image on the left side? The correct way of picking the objects would be in the compositor with a view node: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/de9B4.png). Otherwise for storing the Cryptomatte you'd save them in a multi-layer OpenEXR.

Comment: @RobertGützkow Thanks, indeed it worked when I used it in the Compositor, but I couldn't get them to work when exporting an OpenEXR, the colors are all different when I open it in Affinity Photo. What I did was pluging the Render Layers node outputs to the File Output node, but I'm sure there's something I'm missing.

Comment: Cryptomatte *doesn't* simply store color, how it works and what is stored in the multi-layer OpenEXR is explained in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/157159).

Comment: I'll read that, thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using the pick plug instead of the image or matte plug